# Change a class property from external method using ref

Tags: c#

An error has been occurred while try changing the string property inside class,
but if assign ('f.StartTime' to a string variable it's work but doesn't change the 'StartTime' property)

like:

```
string x = f.StartTime;
ChangeText(ref x);  // There's no error, but f.StartTime didn't change.
//Unless:
f.StartTime = x;
```

of course it's Fake Method...

so i want perform the following code.

```
public class MainClass
{
    public class Foo
    {
        public string StartTime { get; set; }
        public string ToTime { get; set; }
    }

    private void ChangeText(ref string Time)
    {
        Time = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }

    public void SetClassObjects()
    {
        Foo f = new Foo()
        {
            StartTime = "Any Text",
            ToTime = "Any Text"
        };

        ChangeText(ref f.StartTime);

        // An error: A property, indexer or dynamic member access may not be passed as an out or ref parameter
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Strings are immutable, assigning `f.StartTime` to `x` creates a copy of the *value* not of the reference. Hence you need to re-assign `f.StartTime`. The `ref` inclusion will correctly re-assign the reference `x` (to actually point at a new string under `x`), but the reference to `f.StartTime` is lost due to the value-type semantics of strings. Note that strings are reference types, they just follow the semantics of value types.

I would shy away from providing`string` as a `ref` in this instance and instead do something like:

```
f.StartTime = GetText();

private string GetText()
{
    return DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

Or alternatively pass `Foo` into the `ChangeText` method:

```
private void ChangeText(Foo fooItem)
{
    fooItem.Time = DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

Then just `ChangeText(f);`.

If you want to provide a generic mechanism for mutating a property string, you could have an interface:

```
public interface ICanHaveMyTextChanged 
{
    void ChangeText(string newText);
}
```

Which `Foo` implements:

```
class Foo : ICanHaveMyTextChanged 
{
    public string StartTime { get; private set; }

    public void ChangeText(string newText)
    {
        StartTime = newText;
    }
}
```

And then specify the interface as the argument instead of `Foo`:

```
private void ChangeText(ICanHaveMyTextChanged item)
{
    item.ChangeText(DateTime.Now.ToString());
}
```

And call thus:

```
var f = new Foo();
ChangeText(f);
```

Now any class that implements this interface can have it's text changed.

Comment: Thank you sir, i know this but i want generalize this method in a big class to change a string value, not for (Foo Class Only).

Comment: @HadyShaltout I've updated my answer with a more general version using interfaces, but if you want my opinion, stick with the solution where you return a string instead of trying to mutate one.